# Oracle 11gr2 instant client installation

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, installation, client

I have an application that uses Oracle 11gr2. For the Oracle client installation, I first install InstantClient and then run the setup again, choose Custom, and choose "Oracle Database Utilities" since the InstantClient doesn't have exp/imp with it.

My question is, instead of doing 2 steps for installation, how can I just do it once? What corresponding options do I have to select in Custom mode to install InstantClient? I have attached a pic for the complete list of items available.

Thanks.

[image: Oracle 11gr2 Custom client install]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that Oracle Call Interface and Oracle Java Client, plus may be SQL*Plus if you want to be able to run scripts, should be sufficient.